# Encapsulate series of steps within a Monad

Tags: scala, monads

In trying to understand Monads as "a structure that represents computations defined as sequences of steps" : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming)

This example :

```
def optionAdd(x:Option[Int], y:Option[Int]):Option[Int] = 
  for(xx <- x; yy <- y) yield xx+yy
```

taken from [Scala Monad - Full worked example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15095588/scala-monad-full-worked-example). This monad concatenates two Strings in a predefined order.

I'm attempting to wrap these steps within a monad :

```
 1. Get String to be converted to html
 2. Perform series of replace statements on the String to create html compliant String



  def getString = {
    "def test() \n { }"
  }                                               //> getString: => String
  val stringOption = Option(getString);           //> stringOption  : Option[String] = Some(def test() 
                                                  //|  { })
  def createHtmlMonad(x: Option[String]): Option[String] =
    Option(x.get.replace("\n", "<br>").replace("def", "<div style=\"color:red\" </div>"));
                                                  //> createHtmlMonad: (x: Option[String])Option[String]
  val h = createHtmlMonad(stringOption);          //> h  : Option[String] = Some(<div style="color:red" </div> test() <br> { })
```

The method createHtmlMonad is not a Monad ? Can this functionality be encapsulated within a Monad ?

I could just create a new method that encapsulates the series of steps but this is not a Monad :

```
    def getString = {
    "def test() \n { }"
  }                                               //> getString: => String

  def stepsToCreateHtml(stringOption: Option[String]) = {

    val replaceBr = Option(stringOption.get.replace("\n", "<br>"))
    val replaceStyle = Option(replaceBr.get.replace("def", "<div style=\"color:red\" </div>"))

    replaceStyle
  }                                               //> stepsToCreateHtml: (stringOption: Option[String])Option[String]
  val stringOption = Option(getString);           //> stringOption  : Option[String] = Some(def test() 
                                                  //|  { })

  val html = stepsToCreateHtml(stringOption);     //> html  : Option[String] = Some(<div style="color:red" </div> test() <br> { })
                                                  //|
```

Update : 
I think this helps to answer the question. Instead of creating a new monad I re-use the existing Option monad :

```
object t extends App {

  println(parseService.getHtml("").flatMap(convertBr).flatMap(convertStyle))

  def convertBr = (str: String) => Option(str.replaceAll("\n", "<br>"))
  def convertStyle = (str: String) => Option(str.replaceAll("def", "<div style= color : \"red\"></div>"))

}

object parseService {
  def getHtml(str: String): Some[String] = {
    Some("test \n newline def")
  }
}
```

This is based on https://medium.com/@sinisalouc/demystifying-the-monad-in-scala-cc716bb6f534#.xprt8msoc . The monad itself is just a wrapper, the value is how it is composed with the functionality to be implemented, in this case I use the Option monad to compase appending of new Strings. I still do not fully understand monads but feel a little closer.

Comment: `createHtmlMonad` is not a monad, only monad in your code is `Option` monad. You do computation in the context of monad by using `flatMap` which for `M[A]` takes a function `A => M[B]` and returns `M[B]`. Try to read more about monads, maybe not just wiki as that explanation is kind of unclear. Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44965/what-is-a-monad

Comment: @Łukasz please see update

Comment: This is a step in right direction. You should use monad when it does something for you, current code doesn't take advantage of it. `Option` monad is represents some context in which value may be present or not, here, your value is always present. If let's say your actions could fail your  `convertBr` could return `Some(replacedText)` or `None` if replacing failed. Having a many operations of this kind and combining them using monad would make your life easier as the final result after all transformations would be `Some(result)` or `None` if failed (no nested checks).

Comment: Perhaps when you get deeper understanding of some common monads, the general concept will become clearer. You could read about `Option`, `Try`, `Either`, `Future`. Maybe something from scalaz, there is a great presentation on `State` monad here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jg3Uv_YWJqI

Comment: I recommend LYAH - http://learnyouahaskell.com/a-fistful-of-monads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find that it's easier to understand that particular analogy of a monad when it's written in it's for comprehension form,

```
for {
  cbr <- convertBr(parseService.getHtml("")) //step 1
  cs <- convertStyle(cbr) //step 2
} yield cs
```

which is compiled directly to the `flatmap` form which you've written in your segment. Each of the lines is a *step* in this case and the `Option` monad provides the logic of *how* the steps are linked together and interpreted.

In this case the `Option` monad terminates the next steps when the previous step does not return a value which is present, i.e. a `None` but allows the computation to continue when a value is returned i.e. a `Some`.

```
def flatMap[B](f: A => Option[B]): A =  this match {
    case Some(a) => f(a)
    case None => None
}
```

The monad then can be thought of as the *computational context* in which the steps happen with the `flatmap` determining how the computation proceeds.

It's worth noting however that **this is just an analogy/metaphor**. A monad is simly something that follows the *monadic laws*.

The law which is most important can be written in scala as simply,

```
val ab = for {
 a <- genA
 b <- genB
} yield (a, b)

val ba = for {
 b <- genB
 a <- genA
} yield (a, b)

assert(ab == ba)
```