# Are the Streams in Java 8 monads?

Tags: functional-programming, java-8, monads, java-stream

It seems like the [Optional in Java 8 is a monad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19932439/51292).

Are the Streams also monads?

Can anyone identify the endofunctor and the two natural transformations in the optional monad?

Comment: Not knowing Streams very well, I guess it is. Yet, how does it matter? You can't abstract over type constructors in Java, you can't overload on return type either, hence you probably can't write Java code that is polymorphic in the monad constructor.

Comment: It's worth noting that Optional violates the left identity law when handling null values, and is therefore technically not a monad. `Optional.ofNullable(null).flatMap(Optional::of)` yields an empty Optional, while `Optional.of(null)` throws an NPE. Of course, it still offers most of the benefits of monads.

Comment: see [1] that explains that Optional is not a monad. It's also a great introduction to Monads - for java programmers. https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**EDIT** The answer below is **incorrect** (retained here for history).

> Yes, in each case the functor consists of the class and its `map` method, and the two natural transformations are `of` and `flatMap(identity)`.

The correct answer seems to be [here](https://patternsinfp.wordpress.com/2010/12/31/stream-monad/).

Comment: we would need to define: \displaystyle  \begin{array}{lcl} \mathit{return} &::& a \rightarrow \mathit{Stream}\,a \\ \mathit{join} &::& \mathit{Stream}\,(\mathit{Stream}\,a) \rightarrow \mathit{Stream}\,a \end{array}

Comment: The link is nice, but there is no easy way to see if the answer is 'Yes' or 'No'. Please consider updating your question so that people can quickly see what the short answer is.

Comment: @Titulum I would like to remove my answer since it is incorrect, but SO won't let me.

Comment: @n.m. would you be willing to update the question to include a simple 'Yes' or 'No'?

Comment: @Titulum No I want to delete the answer. I do not feel qualified enough to provide an answer. If you want to edit it, go ahead.

Comment: @n.m., No pressure, I don't really know the answer too. That's why [I asked the question too yesterday, which was flagged as duplicate almost immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56687166/can-a-stream-pipeline-be-considered-a-monad)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, `java.util.stream.Stream` satisfies Monad laws.

Following prerequisites are:

1. `Stream` should be *Functor*, i.e. to provide following function `fmap :: (a -> b) -> M a -> M b`.
   If we will look into sources, we will see that it already has function `Stream<R> map(Function<T, R> mapper)`
2. It should have `unit` (a.k.a `return`) operation: `unit :: a -> M a`. This one is obvious: `Stream<T> of(T t)`.
3. It should have `bind` **or** `join` operation:

   1. **`bind :: M a -> (a -> M b) -> M b`** : `Stream<R> flatMap(Function<T, Stream<R>> mapper)`
   2. **`join :: M (M a) -> M a`**: this one is not present in `Stream` but we can infer it from `bind`.

Now we have required functions. But it's not enough yet to call it monad! We need to prove that monad laws are valid. Let's look at them:

**Left identity:** `(return a) bind f <=> f a`

```
        Function<String, Stream<Integer>> f = str -> str.chars().boxed();
        String a = "abc";
        Stream<Integer> left = Stream.of(a).flatMap(f);
        Stream<Integer> right = f.apply(a);
        //left should be same as right
```

**Right identity:** `m bind unit <=> m`

```
        Stream<String> stream = Stream.of("abc", "def");
        Stream<String> left = stream.flatMap(str -> Stream.of(str));
        // left should be same as Stream.of("abc", "def")
```

**Associativity:** `(m bind f) bind g <=> m bind (\x -> f x bind g)`

```
        Function<Integer, Stream<String>> f = integer -> Arrays.stream(Integer.toHexString(integer).split(""));
        Function<String, Stream<BigInteger>> g = string -> Stream.of(string).map(str -> new BigInteger(str, 16));

        Stream<Integer> mLeft = Stream.of(47789, 61453);
        Stream<BigInteger> left = mLeft.flatMap(f).flatMap(g);

        Stream<Integer> mRight = Stream.of(47789, 61453);
        Stream<BigInteger> right = mRight.flatMap(integer -> f.apply(integer).flatMap(g));
        //left should be same as right
```

So it looks like Streams are really monads! But be wary, same situation might happen as with `Optional` which sometimes violates Monadic laws. I have a gut feeling that it might be violated in some cases if you will use `parallel()` because it can change execution order. If you know where it could happen please comment below.

Answer (score 2):

If you know Haskell: Java's Stream is nothing else then Haskell's list monad [] and Java's Optional is nothing else the Haskell's Maybe monad.