# Problems with Java Generics while building a monad

Tags: java, generics, functional-programming, monads

I'm playing around Java code in order to create a functional style monad, but I get struck while using generics and the Java compiler gives me a compilation error if I don't cast my object (though Generics would solve this problem!)

This is the usage:

```
//COMPILATION ERROR! It requires a cast to String
String message = If.of("Hi", s->s!=null).apply(s->s+" guys!").get();
```

Allowed:

This is my monad:

```
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.function.Predicate;

public class If<T, R> {

  private T t;
  private Predicate predicate;

  private If(T t, Predicate predicate) {
    this.t = t;
    this.predicate = predicate;
  }

  public static<T> If of(T t, Predicate predicate) {
    return new If(t, predicate);
  }

  public If<R,R> apply(Function<T, R> function) {
    if(predicate!=null && predicate.test(t)){
        return new If<R, R>(function.apply(t), null);
    }
    return If.of(this.t, null);
  }

  public T get() {
    return t;
  }

}
```

Comment: `public static<T> If of(T t, Predicate predicate) {` -- The return type is raw.

Comment: I guess it should be `Predicate<T>` or so. And it would be helpful to include the error message from the compiler...

Comment: Setting aside the issue of using raw types. What is this monad supposed to do? What would `If.of(1, x -> x > 2).apply(Integer::toString).get()` return? In other words, what happens when the condition is false? Do you expect `null`?

Comment: If the condition is false it returns this. It's like a mapIf it would have existed in Optional monad for example. It applies a transformation only if the Predicate is verified.

Comment: I think either you or me, or both of us are very confused. I'm asking about what do you expect `get` will return. Are you saying that `get` should return a `If<T>`? `get` is not similar to an `Optional.map`. Your `apply` is similar to `Optional.map`. When you `get` an empty `Optional`, you get an exception, right? So what I'm asking is, what do you want to happen when you `get` an `If` when the condition is false?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstood. The method get() must return the wrapped object t (it can be the original object or the transformed object if the Predicate is true)

Comment: Upon further examination of your code, I feel like this monad is kind of useless. You can only meaningfully call `apply` _once_, Any further calls to `apply` will cause the second `return` to execute, so you'll always get back the original object? Is this actually intended or you haven't thought this through?

Comment: And no, `get` can't return _either_ the original object or the transformed object, because they could be different types. The original object is of type `T`, whereas the transformed object is of type `R`. You could use an `Either` monad here, but that kind of defeats the purpose of this `If`, right? Because you still have to check which one it is that is returned. What is it that you are actually trying to accomplish with this `If` monad? If this is just an exercise for monads, there are many other monads that you can write.

Comment: Yes it' just an exercise to get deep into monads and generics. Thanks! If you transform this comment into a response I'll vote it as the right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Andy Turner's answer explained the immediate why your current code does not compile, but your monad seems to have a more fundamental problem - it is not very useful.

According to you, the first call to `apply` should either return the transformed object wrapped in the monad if the condition is true, or the original object wrapped in a monad if the condition is false. But since you are passing `null` as the condition for both cases, any subsequent calls to `apply` will cause the second `return` to be reached, hence always returning the result of the first call to `apply`.

In fact, it is not possible to either return the original object or the transformed object (not in a useful and type-safe way, anyway). To do it type-safely, you'd need an `Either<If<T>, If<R>>` (assuming such a type existed). But to extract the values out of an `Either`, you'd still need an if statement, defeating the purpose of the `If<T>` class.

Apparently, this is just an exercise to practice writing monads. With that being the case, I recommend that you choose another monad to implement, such as `Either`. I also suggest you look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13454347/monads-with-java-8) first.

Answer (score 5):

The direct issue is that the return type of the `of` method is raw:

```
public static<T> If of(T t, Predicate predicate) {
```

You presumably need it to be something like:

```
public static<T> If<T, Something> of(T t, Predicate<T> predicate) {
```

---

I would suggest you don't really want to bake the `R` into the `If`'s type. If you declare it on the method instead, you then have the flexibility to `apply` it to whatever type you need:

```
public class If<T> {
  // ...

  public <R> If<R> apply(Function<T, R> function) {
    if(predicate!=null && predicate.test(t)){
      return new If<>(function.apply(t), null);
    }
    return If.of(this.t, null);
  }

  // ...
}
```

Then your `of` signature can be simply:

```
public static<T> If<T> of(T t, Predicate<T> predicate) {
```

---

If you want your API to be a bit more flexible, add wildcards:

```
public static<T> If<T> of(T t, Predicate<? super T> predicate) {
```

and

```
public <R> If<R> apply(Function<? super T, ? extends R> function) {
```

Comment: Very interesting suggestions, I've tried but in the last return of apply() method it gives me compilation error because it returns an If<T> instead of an If<R>. How to solve this?

Comment: Thanks @Sweeper not null but this. That means returning the monad itself.

Comment: @AlexMawashi oh, right. In that case, you don't need `R` at all: you've got to return an `If<T>`.