# Not able to return object from .flatMap() when acting on a Mono<Boolean>

Tags: java

I have a method `deleteUser()` which returns a custom object `Response`

In this method I am calling method `tryDelete()` which returns a `Mono<Boolean>`. In order to act on the boolean in a non-blocking way I'm using `.flatMap()` with an if / else statement.

```
@Override
public Response deleteUser(String accountId) {
    return tryDelete(accountId).flatMap(isSuccessful -> {
        if (isSuccessful) {
            return buildResponse("happy happy");
        } else {
            return buildResponse("not good");
        }
    });
}
```

tryDelete()

```
public Mono<Boolean> tryDelete(String accountId) {
    return Mono.just(true);
}
```

However, it doesn't compile and I get

> no instance(s) of type variable(s) R exist so that Response conforms to Mono<? extends R>

Answer (score 2):

[`flatMap`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) argument is a function `I -> Mono<O>`, not a function `I -> O` where `I` and `O` are respectively the input and the output types.

If you don't want to [extract the content from the `Mono`](https://www.baeldung.com/java-string-from-mono), you should wrap the `Response` in a new `Mono`.

```
public Mono<CustomResponse> deleteUser(String accountId) {
    return tryDelete(accountId).flatMap(isSuccessful -> {
        if (isSuccessful) {
            return Mono.just(buildResponse("happy happy"));
        } else {
            return Mono.just(buildResponse("not good"));
        }
    });
}

public CustomResponse deleteUserBlocking(String accountId) {
    Boolean isSuccessful = tryDelete(accountId).block();
    if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(isSuccessful)) {
        return buildResponse("happy happy");
    } else {
        return buildResponse("not good");
    }
}
```

Are you sure you don't just want to use [`map`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) (which actually has a `I -> O` as argument)?

```
public Mono<CustomResponse> deleteUser(String accountId) {
    return tryDelete(accountId).map(isSuccessful -> {
        if (isSuccessful) {
            return Mono.just(buildResponse("happy happy"));
        } else {
            return Mono.just(buildResponse("not good"));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: If I use map I need to block() which is not ideal.

Comment: I also forgot to mention the deleteUser() method is overriden so I can't change the signature.

Comment: If you have to return a Response and the method is not somehow async, then you have to block it somewhere...

Comment: I think `.doOnSuccess()` with `.subscribe()` would be non-blocking

Comment: Look at the arguments and return types of doOnSuccess and subscribe: they are not your desired output. deleteUser returns an actual Response object, not a CompletableFuture or a Mono; so, when deleteUser must be blocking.

Comment: Ah yes I see what you mean now. It has to block eventually to return (as it's not returning Mono). I still think using subscribe() would result in less waiting..

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be best not to return `Mono` on `tryDelete` method and do something like that:

```java
public Optional<Account> tryDelete(String accountId) {
    if (repo.existsById(accountId))
        return Optional.of(repo.deleteById(accountId));
    else
        return Optional.empty();
}

public Mono<Response> deleteUser(String accountId) {
    Account deletedAcc = tryDelete(accountId)
                          .orElse(null);

    boolean deleted = deletedAcc == null ? false : true;

    if (deleted)
        return Mono.just(buildResponse("good"));
    else 
        return Mono.just(buildResponse("not happy"));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because I am learning haskell, and I know that there is [monads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13454347/monads-with-java-8), and I know that Optional in Java is monad, and maybe Mono in your code is a monad too, I really want to answer this question.

I learned from a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e6tWJD5q8uw&t=2285s&ab_channel=DevoxxUK) that monad is approximately equal to

1. functor with flatten, or
2. flatMap

In my opinion, monad is some kind of container/box that hold object with extra state of that object.

The example code in the video, is about parsing a string and return a parsed, divided number. Return of the function will be Optional.empty if any of the step is not finished(like parse non digit string to number, in another words, value in Optional is `not presented`):

```
public Optional<Double> codeWithoutFlatMap(String s){
    final Optional<String> split = split(s);
    if (split.isPresent()) {
        final Optional<Double> parse = parse(split.get());
        if (parse.isPresent()) {
            final Optional<Double> result = divide(parse.get());
            if (result.isPresent()) {
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
    return Optional.empty();
}
```

With flatMap, the code is much more precise

```
// this code is exactly equal to code before
public Optional<Double> codeWithFlatMap(String s){
    return split(s)
            .flatMap(split -> parse(split))
            .flatMap(parse -> divide(parse));
}
```

Back to your case, I notice some code can be improved, it is the cause for not compiling:

1. flatMap returns boxed type, for example Optional<Response> or Mono<Response>, you expect method would return a Response, but actually it returns a Mono<Response>
2. the Function inside flatMap, should return a boxed type, like Mono<Response>